# Salvar no exterior o valor de uma variável e depois importar o mesmo em Batch

Tags: cmd, batch

Se eu criar uma variável como essa:

```
set /a EXEMPLO=1
```

"EXEMPLO" vale 1, tem como eu salvar essa informação no meio exterior (em um arquivo) e depois importar esse valor de novo para o mesmo comando? Assim, depois de fechar o prompt de comando, eu poderei "ler" o valor que EXEMPLO tinha antes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim é possível, basta fazer assim para salvar:

```
set /a EXEMPLO=1
>arquivo.txt echo %EXEMPLO%
```

E para ler em outro `.bat` faça isto:

```
set /p OUTRA_VARIAVEL=<arquivo.txt

echo %OUTRA_VARIAVEL%
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado